# SQL LIKE with % query for text in Perl

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I have the following piece of code:

```
$query = "SELECT tac FROM lte_modems WHERE tac = ?";
$check_name = $dbh->prepare($query);
$my_name = "Jo"         
$check_name->execute($my_name);
my @result = $check_name->fetchrow_array();
```

which works perfectly fine.
I would like to change the SQL query to get back names starting with "Jo":
ie my SQL query should be

```
   $query = "SELECT tac FROM lte_modems WHERE tac LIKE '?%'";
```

but this is not working out. any help pls? maybe I need to escape some characters?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the `%` in your parameter. Otherwise you'll get additional quoting as DBI handles that for you.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT tac FROM lte_modems WHERE tac LIKE ?" );
$sth->execute( $my_name . '%' );
```

The trick is really to always let DBI do all the quoting and do none of it yourself. DBI doesn't care if the placeholder `?` is after an equals `=`, a `LIKE` or a `REGEXP` or something else. It escapes quotes properly and adds quotes if necessary. You don't want to interfere with that at all.

Comment: thanks, understood ... but I would also need to include the single quotes. how can i add those?

Comment: @mouthpiec no, you do not need to include the quotes. DBI does that for you. That's my point. ;)

Comment: @mouth If you want to look at what DBI is doing, you can start your program with the environment variable `DBI_TRACE=3|SQL` or set `$check_name->{TraceLevel} = "3|SQL|";` . Also see https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#DBI_TRACE and https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING.

Comment: i think I could have also added the % in the part $my_name = "Jo" . '%'

Comment: @mouthpiec yes, obviously. :)

Comment: @mouthpiec on the other hand, if your input is not variable, why use a variable at all? If the query is always the same, you don't need to use a placeholder. `SELECT tac FROM lte_models WHERE tac LIKE 'JO%'` will work just as well. What I'm trying to say is that changing the input (the `"Jo"`) is a valid solution, but probably it's better to just append the `%` when you pass it to DBI, because you might need it somewhere else in an unaltered form.

Comment: This answer is correct, but the full truth is that `LIKE` is somehow difficult to handle because the match pattern itself might already contain special characters which the database treats specially after `LIKE`. As an example, imagine that `$my_name` already contains a `%` character. The DBI driver will *not* magically quote this for you.

Answer (score 1):

You quoted the `?`, turning it from a placeholder into a string. Use

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tac FROM lte_modems WHERE tac LIKE ?");
$sth->execute($my_name . '%');
```

or

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT tac FROM lte_modems WHERE tac LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')");
```